# VBA search column for a string, and if found Copy the next Cell Data to a new Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've had no luck finding what I am trying to do after hours of failed attempts and scouring the internet. I want to scan a column looking for a string, and if found I want to copy the next cell over's value and paste it in a new sheet, then continue down the column for the next string and copy the value beside it into the next cell down on the other sheet. I've gotten my code to do the copy and paste but I can't figure out how to move the paste location down to the next cell so it doesn't continue to overwrite. Here is what I have so far:

```
For Each cell in SrchRng
     If cell.Value = "1_Complete" Then
          cell.Offset(0,1).Copy Sheets("WO Completion List").[A1]
     End If
Next cell
```

I've tried using an integer i where the A1 cell is listed and then diong the i = i+1 increment in the destination but it doesn't work. I feel as though this is simple but I can't figure it out. Maybe I need to create an Array? I'm new to VBA I'm used to Java or C++.

Quick update:

I wasn't using ".Cells" i left off the "s" so I've gotten it to work. I did this:

```
For Each cell In SrchRng
     If cell.Value = "1_Complete" Then
         cell.Offset(0, 1).Select
         Selection.Copy
         Sheets("WO Completion List").Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         i = i + 1
     End If
 Next cell
```

My question now becomes, is there a better way of doing this? When I run the function it causes the screen to flash a bunch and copies the list to the one sheet then the values disappear and it just seems strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of which row you are copying to and increment. I think the real change here is how you are referencing a range. Instead of `[A1]` use either the format `.Range("A1")` or, for incrementing `.Cells(1,1)` where the first param is the row and the second the column. You could also use `.Offset()` here too, but that can get confusing if things get to nested.

```
'declare an integer to keep track of the row to write to
Dim rowCounter as integer

'set to 1 for row 1 to start
rowCounter = 1
For Each cell in SrchRng
     If cell.Value = "1_Complete" Then
          cell.Offset(0,1).Copy Sheets("WO Completion List").Cells(rowCounter, 1)
          'we wrote out a value, so increment to the rowCounter to the next row
          rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
     End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Thanks @JNevill I noticed I was using .Cell not .Cells right before you answered. Is there a way to do this without the screen freaking out and the copied cells showing up then disappearing? I am not going to be the one using this so I don't want everyone to come ask me why it does that every time they use the spreadsheet.

Comment: Before your code, but in your subroutine, you can shut off the application's ScreenUpdating setting: `application.screenupdating = false`. At the end of your code make sure you toggle that back to True otherwise you'll have some very confused end users.

Comment: You may also find slightly better behavior if, instead of `range.copy... ` you just set the value of one based on the value of the other. Note that this won't copy formatting or formulas though. `Sheets("WO Completion List").cells(rowCounter, 1).value = cell.Offset(0,1).value`.

Comment: That last method worked a lot smoother. I think I tried that at one point but I kept forgetting the s on cells and it was causing me problems. I'm still getting used to VBA. Thanks for your help.